# Reading / Writing Files with File-System and Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filesystems

I'm new to express.js, and I'm using it as my NodeJS backend, serving a standard webpage.

In my express's app.js file I have the usual node dependencies, but I also have file-system included.

Although I'm serving a typical webpage, I'd like to have access to the fs read/write functions. I've included these functions in my express app.js file, but i cannot seem to call them from my webpage's js files. I assume this is some kind of inheritance/scope issue?

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('file-system');
var helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());

[…]

app.use(express.static('../myWebpage/'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../myWebpage/'));
    // res.send('Get Request!')
})

[…]

function readFile( url ){
    fs.readFile(url, 'utf8', function( err, data ){
        if ( err ) {
            console.log( 'error', err );
        } else {
            console.log('file read');
            return data;
        }
    });
}

function saveFile( url, body ){
    fs.writeFile(url, body, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error saving');
            throw err;
        } else {
            console.log('It\'s saved!');
        }
    });
}
```

**Note** The point here is that I'm trying to call the read/save file functions from the myWebpage/js file.

Comment: Can you please include your code?

Comment: @Vasi - Added. I didn't think to add it because it's basically boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** you can't

as I understood you are trying to call read/save function from yours front-end js files, which is served from the myWebpage folder. This is not possible with such transparency.

The problem is that js files running in your backend node.js environment on a server are isolated from yours front-end javascript running inside the browser on a client machine. The only way, they can communicate is through HTTP calls.

In order to do this, you need to create a route, which can be reached from your client. Also, you need to pass parameters via query string: /save?url=path

```
app.get('/read', function(request, response) {
  readFile(request.query.url);
})
```

save route is a little bit more complicated because it needs to use post request.
First, you need to use body-parser middleware in order to parse body parameters:`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());`

Second, you need to create save route

```
app.post('/save', function(request, response) {
  saveFile(request.query.url, request.body.body);
});
```

And in your client js file, you need to make get/post to this routes via requests through xhr: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

In your code has minor mistake.

```
var fs = require('file-system'); // wrong way
var fs = require('fs'); // right way
```

You can import fs module by using these way.

[Sample express.js code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864125/loading-html-stylesheets-in-node-js/44864291#44864291)

Comment: This does not fix the scope issue. I still get 'fs not defined' when calling the functions. I have fs installed correctly.

Comment: The fs is default module of node js. You don't want to install it. Can you show your error?